# How can I show data from mysql in html tables? Using netbean Java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I am wrong here c12. rs=c12. st. executeUpdate (SQL); I don't know how can I get rid of this error all my code is here please executes it and tells about my fault.I want to show mysql table in html using table tag

**myservlet5.java**

```
       public class myservlet5 extends HttpServlet {
       private Object executeUpdate;

        private static class executeUpdate {

        public executeUpdate() {
        }
         }
         private Object rs;
          private Object st;
           protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
              PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
               String name=request.getParameter("t1");
                String abc=request.getParameter("t2");

                aaaa c1=new aaaa();

                try{

                 String Sql="insert into teacher1(id,name) values('"+name+"','"+abc+"')";

                 c1.st.executeUpdate(Sql);   
                 }
               catch(SQLException ex)
                  {

               out.println(ex);

               }
               aaaa c12=new aaaa();
            try{

            String Sql="Select * from teacher1";
```

.               c12.rs=c12.st.executeUpdate(Sql);

```
            out.println("<table border=1>");
            while(c12.rs.next()){

           String name1=c12.rs.getString("id");

          String abc1=c12.rs.getString("name");

           out.println("<tr>");
           out.println("<td>"+name1+"</td>");
           out.println("<td>"+abc1+"</td>");
           out.println("</tr>");  
            }
           out.println("</table>");
            }
            catch(SQLException ex)
            try {
              out.println("<html>");
              out.println("<head>");
              out.println("<title>Servlet myservlet5</title>");            
              out.println("</head>");
              out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<h1>Servlet myservlet5 at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");

                 out.println("</body>");
               out.println("</html>");
             } 

             finally {            
            out.close();
           }
         }
```

**index.jsp**

```
         <html>
         <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

         </head>
         <body>
         <form action="myservlet5"  method="GET"    >

        First name:<br> 
        <input type="text" name="t1"/> 
        <br> 
        Last name:
        <br> 
        <input type="text" name="t2" /> 
        <br>  <br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

**error**

```
    HTTP Status 500 -

    type Exception report

    message

    description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of expression 
    myservlet5.processRequest(myservlet5.java:67)
    myservlet5.doGet(myservlet5.java:131)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5.27 logs.

     Apache Tomcat/5.5.2
```

Comment: Post the code with line number, Error clearly says there is a compilation error at line 67 in myservlet5.java. Netbeans will not throw compilation error, Do you have Eclipse? If you run the same in eclipse, then you can find the error easily at compile time.

Comment: Post code for the class aaaa too.